# Custom List view with button : make visible on some condition

Tags: android, android-listview

I am getting data from json parsing from URl and depending on some data from json I need to make the customized list-view button visible otherwise its in invisible state.
If condition is like `String == "123"` then I need to set the button visible.
the below code set the button to visible but when i scroll back, it will appear in some other rows as well. Its is not appearing correctly. The button should appear only in row which satisfy the condition. How can solve this?.

In my layout I set the button like below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"      
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView     
        android:id="@+id/list_image"   
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of program-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="title Name"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- category Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="subtitle" />

<!-- start time -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="time"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend button   -->  
 <Button android:id="@+id/watch"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/watchnow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And my getView code is like below:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;


    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);


        final TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.subtitle); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.time); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image


        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);


        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_NAME));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_PR));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_DES));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_PID), thumb_image);


        if(duration.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("123456")){
            Button watch = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.watch);
            watch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: use boolean flag, set it according to your string each time.. and then check it when you set the value..

Comment: then whats the problem ,with your code

Comment: @CobraAjgar the button is appearing in some rows which do not satisfy that condition also.

Comment: Can you post your single_row.xml and logcat trace.

Comment: @Gunaseelan edited question.Added single_row.xml layout

Comment: Till now your code is correct only. May I know where you defined `inflater`?

Comment: @Gunaseelan inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your `inflater if` as follows

```
if(convertView==null){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);
}
```

And then define your button initialize in outside the if as follows.

```
Button watch = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.watch);
if(duration.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("123456")){                
            watch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Just try. I Think this is the only problem and hope this will help. If not please let me know.

Comment: No this not worked. i displayed in some row. not in correct place.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     Button watch = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.watch);
  if(duration.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("123456")){

        watch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  else{
    watch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

can u try this

```
 Button watch = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.watch);                                                                                  
    if(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_DES).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("123456") 
    { 
      watch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
      watch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

....
...

    return v;
```